# store function output in an array

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, libpq

I have the follwoing function which works fine, BUT I am not sure if it is storing anything in the array.

```
DECLARE 
     _r record;
     point character varying[] := '{}';
     i int := 0;

BEGIN



FOR _r IN EXECUTE ' SELECT a.'|| quote_ident(column_name) || ' AS point
       FROM ' || quote_ident (table_name) ||' AS a'
LOOP

       point[i] = _r;
       i = i+1;

END LOOP;

RETURN point;
END;
```

What I am after is to have an array that from the javascript side i can traverse and read each value stored on the array. Is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: Correct your tags. How the question relates with sqlserver and postgis?

Comment: since I am using spatial data as the column data which each row holds a point value @Hamlet Hakobyan.

Comment: I think Correct tags means, `correctly tag your question`. What *db server* your question related to?

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried to print `point` value via `RAISE`?

Comment: What does it really RAISE.? I am stull new to plpgsql @vyegorov

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in PL/pgSQL or PostgreSQL has nothing to do with arrays in javascript or php.

If you're working with `libpq`-aware client, like php, then any query to the databases will return a set of records, which can be accumulated into the internal array variable of the calling party, like [`pg_fetch_array()` of php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php).

If you're working with thin clients, like javascript is, you will need to return data in the format suitable for javascript to understand. You will need to have a server-side data providing service, that will obtain results from the PostgreSQL via `libpq` native interface and convert it to the javascript-ready one, like `JSON`. PostgreSQL has native support for the `XML` data type and also `JSON` (a bit limited at the moment). Not sure if that will help you much though.

As to the PL/pgSQL functions, I really recommend reading [official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) on this language. In order to see the value of `point` at runtime, use this statement:

```sql
RAISE NOTICE 'point = %', point;
```